# i want to add flash file in my windows mobile application.

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6, windows-mobile-5.0

I am developing application in vb.net. please help me how to add a flash file in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on Google searching for "windows .net flash control."  I looked for the COM reference as specified in the article using Visual Studio 2010 and was able to add it to a test application very quickly.

http://weblogs.asp.net/twalters/archive/2003/12/29/46265.aspx